# Testing of significant mean/median difference between two computed log-normal distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, mean, choice-modeling

I don´t know if this is possible to test, but I have estimated two mixed logit regressions on two different datasets and the resulting coefficients of the independent variables are assumed to be lognormally distributed.

Subsequently I have divided the coefficients for time and money in each regression in order to get a median value of the willingness to pay distribution (which is also assumed to be lognormally distributed). I also calculate standard errors for these ratios using the delta method. My question now is if it´s possible to test whether these medians are statistically different from each other? I don´t have a vector of individual values for the coefficients or their ratios, I just have the computed medians (or means) and associated standard errors.

I have seen in the literature that for this type of data (marginal values of time and money) the coefficients most likely are log-normally distributed.
The model is a binary choice model formulated as following: U = *coef*m + *coef*t + errorterm.

with m= money   t=time

U is either 1 or 0 in each choice situation.

Comment: Why are you assuming the coefficients are lognormally distributed, as opposed to the more usual assumption that they are Gaussian?  Perhaps you could more fully describe your model?

Comment: This is a good question, I have seen in the literature that for this type of data (marginal values of time and money) the coefficients most likely are lognormally distributed. The model is a binary choice model formulated as following: U = coef*m+ coef*t+ error   with m= money   t=time         U is either 1 or 0 in each choice situation

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.